# Newline created before input when using gets or gets.chomp

Tags: ruby

Okay, so when I do code like:

```
puts "Hallo: "
response = gets.chomp
```

What I want is the user to see something like this:

```
Hallo: _
```

(With the underscore being the text input area) But instead, they see something more like this

```
Hallo:
_
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: use `print` instead of `puts`

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sergio said you need to use `print` instead of `puts`, the difference is that `print` outputs the raw version without any modifications. `Puts` on the other hand adds a newline at the end.

`puts 'Hallo: "` is the same as `print "Hallo: \n"`

Comment: Hmm it works on my console, what do you mean exactly with 'will not work' ?

Comment: I see what you did there, haha :)